# Model is not updating while submitting form AJAX Asp.Net MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have got a MVCapplication where I am collecting details on form having KENDO controls, and along side I can update couple of dropdown controls using AJAX.

The problem I am facing currently that, when I submit the form with changed values in dropdown, and other controls doesn't updates the model, and it remains the same, even if the form shows the updated values, the model retains the old values.

I have tried all sorts of solutions and googled enough but no success. I am putting my code below to show what I am doing at the moment, anyone there, could look at it and guide me as what am I doing wrong.

**VIEW**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
 .Name("ddlDateRange")
 .DataTextField("Name")
  .DataValueField("Id")
  .BindTo(Model.ReportIntervals)
  .Events(e => 
   {
      e.Change((@<text>
       function()
       {
          var selectedDateRange = $("#ddlDateRange").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
           $.ajax({
                   url: '@Url.Action("ChangeStartEndDates")',
                   type: 'POST',                                                                    
                   data: JSON.stringify({ selectedDateRange: selectedDateRange }),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: true,
                   success: function (data) {   

                    $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(data.StartGamingDate);
                    $("#EndDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(data.EndGamingDate);                                                                 
                                                        },
                   error: function () { alert('Error in DateRange dropdownlist'); }
                                                    });
                    }
                                            </text>));
                     })
```

### )

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.StartGamingDate)
.Name("StartDate")
.Events(e =>
{
   e.Change((@<text>
   function()
   {
      var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
      var endDate = $("#EndDate").val();
     $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("ChangeDateRangeName")',
     type: 'POST',                                                                    
     data: JSON.stringify({ startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     async: true,
     success: function (data) {
          $("#ddlDateRange").data("kendoDropDownList").text(data.ReportInterval.Name);
      },
      error: function () { alert('Error in StartDate DatePicker'); }
      });
     }
     </text>));
     }))
```

---

```
   @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.EndGamingDate)
   .Name("EndDate")
   .Events(e =>
   {
     e.Change((@<text>
     function()
     {
       var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
       var endDate = $("#EndDate").val();
       $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("ChangeDateRangeName")',
          type: 'POST',                                                                    
          data: JSON.stringify({ startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate }),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          success: function (data) {
            $("#ddlDateRange").data("kendoDropDownList").text(data.ReportInterval.Name);
          },
          error: function () { alert('Error in EndDate DatePicker'); }
          });
          }
          </text>));
      }))
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
**MODEL VALUES FORTHIS ACTION**

systemAuditReportViewModel.StartGamingDate = "01/01/2013";
systemAuditReportViewModel.EndGamingDate = "31/12/2013";
systemAuditReportViewModel.ReportInterval.Id = 30;
systemAuditReportViewModel.ReportInterval.Name = "Last Calender Year";

[HttpPost]        
    public JsonResult ChangeStartEndDates(int selectedDateRange)        
    {
        SystemAuditReport systemAuditReportViewModel = new SystemAuditReport();

        Nullable<DateTime> startGamingDate;
        Nullable<DateTime> endGamingDate;

        IG.General.Web.Model.ReportInterval reportInterval = new IG.General.Web.Model.ReportInterval();
        reportInterval.Id = selectedDateRange;

        IG.General.Web.Model.ReportIntervalFactory.GetDateRange(reportInterval, out startGamingDate, out endGamingDate);

        systemAuditReportViewModel.StartGamingDate = startGamingDate;
        systemAuditReportViewModel.EndGamingDate = endGamingDate;

        return Json(systemAuditReportViewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


**MODEL VALUES FOR THIS ACTION**

systemAuditReportViewModel.StartGamingDate = "27/03/2014";
systemAuditReportViewModel.EndGamingDate = "27/03/2014";
systemAuditReportViewModel.ReportInterval.Id = 2;
systemAuditReportViewModel.ReportInterval.Name = "Today";

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenerateReport(SystemAuditReport systemAuditReportViewModel)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

        ReportContainer reportContainer = new ReportContainer();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {               
            systemAuditReportViewModel.ReportPath = "/reports/";
            //systemAuditReportViewModel.StartGamingDate = startDate;
            //systemAuditReportViewModel.EndGamingDate = endDate;

            this.CreateReport(systemAuditReportViewModel, out reportContainer);
        }

        return View(reportContainer);
    }
```

Comment: How are you persisting your model? In `ChangeStartEndDates` You get a `new ReportInterval()` each time and it doesn't look like it is persisted in any manner?

Comment: @Dave, I was thinking about persisting the model by using TempData, ViewBag etc but I don't find it correct way do persisting the model, but do you think is that the reason, I am not getting the updated model in my post?

Comment: Possibly, to be honest I can't visualise what it is you are trying to achieve so it's hard to be able to help in a constructive way; it's definitely worth remembering that the web is stateless and so you need to implement a way of saving/retrieving the state of objects yourself.

Comment: All I want to do is, when I change the values of the form and update the model, the updated model should retain the changed values on view for next action process.

Comment: There are many solutions to persisting data - as you said you can use TempData or ViewBag but these are very short term mechanisms. More long terms solutions usually use a database for persistence; it depends on the use of the data which will work best for you

Comment: @Dave, I have used TempData at the moment for the solution to my current problem. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

We had struggled with this a bit as well.  The binding is a little tricky with templates.  You have to name the DropDownList the same as the model's bound index.

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
  .BindTo("#=Model.EntityClassId")
  .DataTextField("Value")
  .DataValueField("Id")
  .Name("EntityClassId")
  .OptionLabel(MyApp.Resources.Text.DamageTypeOptionLabel)
  .AutoBind(true)
  .DataSource( source => source
     .Read( read=>read.Action("SomeMethod", "SomeController"))
     .ServerFiltering(true)
   )
   .Events(events => events
     .Select("onDamageTypeSelected")
     .Change("onDamageTypeChanged")
     .DataBound("onDamageTypeDatabound")
   )
   .HtmlAttributes(new{style="height:21px;vertical-align:center"})
)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but I have resolved this issue long back.